# Why does the Alt key not trigger my low-level keyboard hook?

Tags: delphi, winapi, keyboard, hook

I am experimenting with Keyboard hooks, and it seems as if the <kbd>Alt</kbd> key (amongst other command keys) are not being hooked, and I can't figure out why?

Below is the Keyboard hook with some debug code in it which prints out the vkCode, the scanCode and the lpChar readings.

It works with all keys basically, but not with <kbd>Alt</kbd> and <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> etc

```
function LowLevelKeybdHookProc(nCode, wParam, lParam : integer) : integer; stdcall;
// possible wParam values: WM_KEYDOWN, WM_KEYUP, WM_SYSKEYDOWN, WM_SYSKEYUP
var info : ^KeybdLLHookStruct absolute lParam;
    lpChar : word;
    kState : TKeyboardState;

begin
result := CallNextHookEx(kHook, nCode, wParam, lParam);
with info^ do
  case WParam of
    WM_KEYDOWN : begin
      GetKeyboardState(kState);

      Form1.Memo1.Text:=Form1.Memo1.Text+'vkCode: '+inttostr(vkCode)+
             ' scanCode: '+inttostr(scanCode)+
             ' lpChar: '+inttostr(lpChar)+;
    end;
  end;
end;
```

Comment: As an aside, I'm not terribly keen on the use of both a with and absolute in the same function. But that's your business in the end.

Comment: I do not quite understand what you mean David

Comment: `with` is heavily frowned upon because it merges namespaces and absolute is somewhat esoteric. Many discussions available on this site and others. What about the actual question that you asked? Please tell me that you are not still stuck? If my answer is wrong, please let me know.

Answer (score 5):

To detect the <kbd>ALT</kbd> key going down, you need to respond to `WM_SYSKEYDOWN`.

Note also that you are ignoring the value of `nCode`. You must read the documentation very carefully and do what it says.

> A code the hook procedure uses to determine how to process the message. If nCode is less than zero, the hook procedure must pass the message to the CallNextHookEx function without further processing and should return the value returned by CallNextHookEx.
>
> This parameter can be one of the following values.
>
> HC_ACTION (0). The wParam and lParam parameters contain information about a keyboard message.

Answer (score 0):

To detect <kbd>Alt</kbd> key, you need to check for Context Code (bit 29 of `lParam`) flag

```
bAltPressed := (lParam and (1 shl 29)) = (1 shl 29);
```

As the [documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms646267(v=vs.85).aspx#_win32_Keystroke_Message_Flags) say:

> Context Code 
>   The context code indicates whether the ALT key was down
>   when the keystroke message was generated. The code is 1 if the ALT key
>   was down and 0 if it was up.